# sequence diagram with detail in a Model View Template architecture

Tags: django, uml

I am trying to realize the design of an application developed with the Django framework but i have a problem with the sequence diagram details .
In fact , i would to realize this sequence diagram with details to show the views / model and the template relation .
Any one can help me?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you have some SD already? Can you show that, please?

Comment: i can't insert a image that contains the SD :(

Comment: Just google it: https://blog.chattyhive.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Django_mvc.png

Comment: For now just place it on a public server and someone with more reputation can add it to your question.